# SSHCore Framework can't run in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ssh

I have downloaded SSHCore  source code which uses libssh2 library.
That code build successfully, but as i put that in my code and build it, it builds successfully but after running it gives me this error:

dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SSHCore.framework/Versions/A/SSHCore
  Referenced from: /Users/mac04/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.0/Applications/541D1C93-3E50-4932-841C-2D63F5F7FF10/SSH.app/SSH
  Reason: image not found

If any one has used this then please help me to solve this issue.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run 3rd party frameworks on iOS.

Have you followed [these instructions](http://sites.google.com/site/olipion/cross-compilation/libssh2) to turn it into a library that can be used on the iPhone?

Comment: so can you briefly explain how can i use SSHCore framework in my application?

Comment: @dishant - that wasn't the question you asked.